# phpMyAdmin doesn't show login form

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I have WAMP installed on localhost, and when I go to phpMyAdmin page (I got 4.9.2 version with wamp) it shows no login form (as shown in the [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne19N.png))

I'm using: Apache 2.4.41, PHP 7.3.12, MariaDB 10.4.10

I checked error logs of Apache, PHP and MariaDB and they seem to show no errors

I have Win 7 as OS